# Can you make SwiftUI open a view from a different direction other than right to left?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, swift5

I have the code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), label: {
    Text("Main Menu")
        .font(Font.custom("ComicNeue-Bold", size: 20))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
})
```

And whenever I press it the ContentView() slides in from the right. Even if I add

```
.transition(.move(edge: .leading))
```

to the NavigationLink it still slides in from the right. Is it possible to make it open from the left? or any other direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a way of changing the sliding direction (sliding behavior in general) using Nav views. However if you want custom transitions I suggest using a GeometryReader like so

```
@State private var index: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { _ in
        
        if self.index == 0 {
            
            FirstView().transition(.move(edge: .leading)
            
        } else {
            
            SecondView().transition(.move(edge: .leading)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```